Trouble creating a pointer to a class as an attribute
I want to make a state manager system for my SFML game. I want game class to contain a pointer to the StateManager object that is going to be created in one of the initialization functions.
I want the StateManager class to have a "game" attribute which is a pointer to an object of Game class.
When I try to build the project the compiler throws following errors:
StateManager.h(7,7): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
StateManager.h(7,7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
StateManager.h(7,22): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Here is the code:
Game.h:
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <vector>

#include "StateManager.h"

class Game
{
    sf::Clock clock;            
    sf::RenderWindow *window = nullptr;         
    
    std::vector<sf::VertexArray> components;    

    StateManager* stateManager = nullptr;

    void handleEvents(sf::Event event); 
    void pollEvents();                       
    void update(sf::Time time);
    void render();                          
    void run();                     
    void initStates();
    void initWindow();                  
    void initComponents();
    void init();                                
public:
    Game();
};

StateManager.h
#pragma once

#include "Game.h"

class StateManager
{
    Game *game = nullptr;
public:
    StateManager(Game* _game);
};

StateManager.cpp
#include "Game.h"
#include "StateManager.h"

StateManager::StateManager(Game *_game)
{
    this->game = _game;
}

I probably made a stupid mistake somewhere as I'm new to programming in c++. I have no idea what is wrong with this code, I tried searching online but I didn't found anything helpful.

You have a classical circular include dependency. You solve it by not including header files in your header files, and use forward declarations instead. You can (and need to) include all the needed header files (in any order) in the source files though.

Only include what you use.  StateManager.h does not use Game.h — so StateManager.h should not #include Game.h.  Likewise, Game.h does not use StateManager.h — so don't include it.  (Both do need a forward declaration.  But neither needs the full declaration.)

The mistake is StateManager.h includes Game.h and Game.h includes StateManager.h. You can't have that.

Or give Game an abstract base class (interface) in a seperate header file and use that in both your game and manager headers.  This will have the added value of making your manager unit testable (you can now inject a mocked game object). If you expect Game to always be a valid object pass it in as a reference instead of a pointer.
